# What Function to use when using a transformer that references multiple columns in a SQL database

Tags: sql, c

Basically, I'm looking to build a function along of the lines of

"`If invoiceAmountDocCurrencyNorm = currentOpenAmount while refKey13 is not null`, then display the `currentDisputeAmount` field. Otherwise display `invoiceAmountNorm` field"

I originally wrote this function as a Hail Mary but no luck:
`(currentOpenAmount == invoiceAmountDocCurrencyNorm AND referenceKey13 != null) ? currentDisputeAmount : invoiceAmountDocCurrencyNorm)`

Comment: That doesn't look like SQL.

Comment: It's not clear to me how `if x == y while z then a else b` works. In particular having the `while` be part of a condition. Is it `if x == y AND z then a else b`?

Comment: As SQL, assuming "while refKey13 is null" means "and refKey13 is null" this would be `select case when invoiceAmountDocCurrencyNorm = currentOpenAmount and refKey13 is not null then currentDisputeAmount else invoiceAmountNorm end from someTable`. Have a look at this [SQL Case tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Comment: @Schwern Yep! That's essentially what I'm trying to achieve. Not entirely sure what the language is as our company DB is SQL but this transformer framework very much is not